# With swift, is there a framework equivalent to pandas in python to perform data analysis (read datasets, delete or insert column, rename them)?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipad, data-analysis

I would like to know if someone knows if there is ***a framework like Python's pandas in swift or objective-c(preferably Swift) for an iOS application.***

I would like to have a library that could parse a csv, json (whatever type of file) and have a **dataset object** with **rows** and **columns**.

My first goal is to be able to perform whatever operation is needed, maybe insert and delete columns, rename columns, make filters, etc etc.